# C/C++ How to calculate the streakedness of numerical data sets?

Tags: c++, c, algorithm, math, statistics

Would anyone know how to use C/C++ to calculate the streakedness of data? The definition of streakedness is how many deviations away from the mean(i.e running average a numerical data streak. Thank you for your help.

[EDIT] From our company's chief software architect, here is the requirement for a statistical measure. Could someone please define a statistical formula based onour architect's definition of data streakedness? -- February 19th 2013 8:00AM

Equal numbers are a streak. 1,2,3,3,3,4,5 has a streak of 7.

Case A: 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13 has a longest streak of 13.

Case B: 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,3,8,9,10,11,12 has a longest streak of 7, a second smaller streak of  6.

Case C: 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,1,2,3,4,5,6  has a longest streak of 7, and a second smaller streak of 6.

Case D: 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,1,2,3,1,2,1 has a longest streak of 7, a second smaller streak of 3, and a third smallest streak of 2

Case E: 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,6,5,4,1,2,3 has a longest streak of 7, and a second smaller streak of 3.

Case F: 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,6,5,4,3,2,1 has a longest streak of 7, and no smaller streaks.

The cases A – F are ordered in ‘most sorted to least sorted’, but all have the same length longest streak. Using the averages of streak length is not appropriate:

A: Average = 13/1 = 13

B: Average = (7+6)/2 = 6.5

C: Average = (7+6)/2 = 6.5

D: Average = (7+3+2)/3 = 4

E: Average = (7+3)/2  = 5

F: Average = 7/1 = 7

Factoring in non-streaks (counting them as 1’s):

A: Average = 13/1 = 13

B: Average = (7+6)/3 = 4.3

C: Average = (7+6)/2 = 6.5

D: Average = (7+3+2+1)/4 = 3.25

E: Average = (7+1+1+1+3)/5 = 2.6

F: Average = (7+1+1+1+1+1+1)/7 = 1.85

A variable R can be used to indicate how many deviations away from the mean a particular streak is. According to the disclosed embodiment, the level of a streak can be defined not just in (integer*deviation) distances from the mean but also as (integer*fraction_of_deviation) distances. To accomplish this, a variable R-factor can be used. The R-factor indicates the separation between two successive R-levels in terms of a fraction of the deviation. By varying the R-factor, streaks can be ranked as required. However, the "credibility" of the streak should also be considered, and included in a ranking mechanism. The deviation within the streak is an obvious measure of how staggered the data is within the streak. A good streak should be less staggered, or in other words, have less deviation. For this reason, a very high level streak is considered to be good, even if its deviation is more than what would normally be desired. Thus, while the level R influences the ranking positively, the deviation within the streak influences it negatively.

Comment: What additional information would be required to answer this question? Thank you.

Comment: hrrrrm. looks alot like homework. I would use the http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root-mean-square_deviation ( what a coincidence... the R variable sounds like the residuals :-) ) or compare the predicted quantiles with the actuall results.

Comment: `What additional information would be required to answer this question?` - What have you tried? Where are you stuck? Seems like you just copied and pasted the assignement, some effort on your part is required

Comment: Najzero, This is not a homwework question. We are designing a data profiler to mesaure the descriptive statictics of numeric data stored in commercial relational databases. We just read the root-mean square deviation wikipedia link. How might RMSD be used to calculate the streakedness of data? Wht is your opinion of using a higher statistical moment such as kurtosis? Thank you for your reply.

Comment: @Mike, We have tried 1)Longest increasing Subsequence and 2) Standard Deviation 3) Running Average to measure the streakedness of data? But, customers want more statistical mesaures. Thank you for your reply.

Comment: This question may fits [Cross Validated](http://stats.stackexchange.com/) or [Mathematics](http://math.stackexchange.com/) better.

Comment: @timrau, Thank you for your reply. We just posted the same question on Stack Exchange mathematics.

Comment: @timrau, Thequestion has been posted on Stack Exchange  mathematics for over 30 minutes. Nobody has answered yet. Most likely, because it is a programming question. Thank you for your help.

Comment: @Frank IMHO you haven't come up with a precise definition of "streakedness" (say, an explicit formula). Once the definition is ready, the C/C++/any_language implementation will be relatively straightforward. That's why I think it is a question in statistics and/or mathematics, not in programming.

Comment: @timrau, I precisely agree with you. The definition of "streakedness" is a trade secret. So, I will have to ask our company architectal director to design a concrete example. Thank you for your reply.

Comment: Our software director has just defined streak as "a string of more than one consecutive ordered list members". Could someone please define a statistical measure whch best pertains to our software director's definition.? Thank you.

Comment: So, the content of a streak does not affect the "streakedness" of a sequence? How do you define a "mean" and "deviation" for streaks?

Comment: @Joni, Could you please explain the reason the content of a streak does not affect the "streakedness" of a sequence? THank you for your reply.

Comment: That's what I understand from your examples: the only thing you want to measure is how many streaks there are and how long they are.

Comment: @Joni, Yes, we are interested only in the length of the longest streak. However, to find a a streak, we currently have to examine the contents of the data. I agree with you that once we know the length of the streak, we can forget about the content of the streak. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not at all clear what you want from this measure. If you don't care about the streak contents you could use the sum of squares of streak lengths divided by the square of the total length. This measure would be always between 0 and 1. It would be exactly 1 if the entire sequence is a single streak, slightly less if it's mostly one long streak, and 1/length if it has no streaks at all. For your cases this measure comes out as

```
A: Average = 13²/13² = 1.0000
B: Average = (7²+6²)/13² = 0.5030
C: Average = (7²+6²)/13² = 0.5030
D: Average = (7²+3²+2²+1²)/13² = 0.3728
E: Average = (7²+1²+1²+1²+3²)/13² = 0.3609
F: Average = (7²+1+1+1+1+1+1)/13² = 0.3254
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply, Joni. I will try to show it our software director and architect later today. Thank you.

Comment: @@Joni, Thank you for the calculations of the test cases. If I hear from our software director and architect, I will approve your answer.  Also, coud you please comment on the applicability of Chauvenet's criteria to cases A, B, C, D, E and F. Thank you.

Comment: To what do you want to apply Chauvenet's criteria?

Comment: @@Joni, Chavenet's criterion might be used to prune the "data outliers" from the data subsequences underlying the data streaks. Thank you for your help.

Comment: @@Joni, Wikipedia states that , "suppose a value is measured in several trials as 9, 10, 10, 10, 11, and 50. The mean is 16.7 and the standard deviation 14.92. 50 differs from 16.7 by 33.3, slightly more than two standard deviations. The probability of taking data more than two standard deviations from the mean is roughly 0.05. Six measurements were taken, so the statistic value (data size multiplied by the probability) is 0.05×6 = 0.3. Because 0.3 < 0.5, according to Chauvenet's criterion, the measured value of 50 should be discarded." Thank you for your help.

Comment: The examples you give above don't look like they have been generated by a normal distribution so the criteria doesn't really apply, your real data might be different though. If this is time series data you should apply the criteria locally, otherwise trends in the data make outliers hard to detect..

Comment: @@Joni, Yes, I agree with you that the Wikipedia examples are contrived. They are not from a normal distribution. If we assume a normal distribution of data points, might we use the Chauvenet criteria to detect outliers? Thank you for your help.

Comment: It may make sense; depends on how you obtained the data and what you are trying to accomplish with it. For example if the outliers are produced by measurement or data entry errors it does make sense to remove them.

Comment: @@Joni, Our software architect and I agree with your comment. Thank you for your help.

Comment: May I ask what your professional opinion is of the following statement? : "Test's such as Grubbs' and Dixon's do take proper account of the distribution of the extreme order statistics from a normal distribution and should be used over Chauvenet ". Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: @@Joni, May I ask what your professional opinion is of the following statement? : "Test's such as Grubbs' and Dixon's do take proper account of the distribution of the extreme order statistics from a normal distribution and should be used over Chauvenet". Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: @Frank, it's probably true: Chauvenet's test removes "unlikely" data points without taking into account that in a big sample you can expect to see unlikely events. I'm not a statistician, I don't know how Grubb's or Dixon's tests are justified, you'll probably get a more expert answer at http://stats.stackexchange.com

Comment: @@Joni, Thank you for your reply. We will try stats.stackexchange.com and reading the book Pharmacueutical Statistics by Dr. Dixon, 1979. Could we continue to stay in touch on this topic via Stack Overflow?

Comment: Thank you for your reply. We will try stats.stackexchange.com and reading the book Pharmacueutical Statistics by Dr. Dixon, 1979. Could we continue to stay in touch on this topic via Stack Overflow?

Answer (score 2):

Sorry if this is off base, but I'm looking at this from an image processing perspective.

One of the more interesting methods I've seen for analyzing scatterplots is "graph-theoretic scagnostics" or simply "scagnostics" (scatterplot diagnostics) proposed by Tukey, later written up by Wilkinson. In addition to "stringiness," there are several other interesting shape/cluster identifiers.

If your data is in 2-space or in 3-space, there are some image processing algorithms that can identify streaks of data, but I'd have to see some sample data plots/images to provide any further suggestions.

Comment: Your idea sounds promising. I will show it our company's chief architect and software director later this morning. Thank you for your idea. I will let you know ASAP if our company's chief architect wants to adopt your idea. Thank you very much.

Comment: @@Rethunk, Would you have time today to  look at our company's sofware architects' examples in the edit above in the original question? I apologize for leaving out our software architect's examples. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Could you please let us know if Chauvanet's criterion maight apply to calculate data streakedness? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chauvenet%27s_criterion Thank you for your help.

Comment: Sorry, I just had the chance to read this 2 days after you posted your request. Since you've accepted the answer from Joni, I assume you're all set. Please let me know otherwise and I'll try to help, though I only check stackoverflow.com sporadically according to my work schedule.

Comment: @@Rethunk, We would be very grateful if you help us solve this problem amd read your posted answer to our question. I know your work sechdule is very busy . So, we will be patient. Thank you for your reply.

Comment: Frank, in an earlier comment you wrote "customers want more statistical measures." Is the sequential data you provided real data? Do you have more sample sets--tens, hundreds, thousands of data sets that I might use to test? Having a large population of both typical and atypical data could hep to determine the likelihood of a streak (and hence its relative measure). For example, are all changes equally likely (e.g. 1,2,3,4 occurs just as often as 1,2,3,7 and 1,2,3,1)? Does the break in the streak always result in a decrease in value:  1, 2, 3, ... N, followed by a value less than N?

Comment: @@Rethunk, I agree 100% with your comment. I will try to show it to our software architect and director tomorrow AM. Our software architect is very busy. So, it may take me a few days to get the answers to your excellent questions back to you. Please stay in touch. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Could you please reconsider Chauvanets' criteria for pruning the "data outliers" from the data subsequences underlying the data streaks? Thank you for your reply.

Comment: @@Rethunk,Could you please reconsider Chauvanets' criteria for pruning the "data outliers" from the data subsequences underlying the data streaks? Thank you for all of your help.

Comment: I'm not sure Chauvenet's criterion is the best means to filter data in this case. There's not enough data to judge that at this point.

Comment: @@Rethunk, May I ask what would be the best means other than Chauvanet's criterion to filter data in this case? Also, how many data points would be required to judge "data outliers" using Chauvanet's criterion? Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: May I ask what would be the best means other than Chauvanet's criterion to filter data in this case? Also, how many data points would be required to judge "data outliers" using Chauvanet's criterion? Thank you very much for your help

Comment: I can take a look at this later this week. Having more data (and preferably real data) would help a lot.

Comment: We will wait patiently for you to look at this(e.g. Chauvanet's criterion) later this week. Thank you for your reply.

Comment: @@Rethunk, We will wait patiently for you to look at this(e.g. Chauvanet's criterion) later this week. Thank you for your reply.

Comment: Frank, work has been extremely busy for me, and I won't have time to get to this. I would suggest following up with Joni.

Comment: I understand how extremely busy you are. Could you please just answer two little questions (Question 1) Do you agree with the following statement? : "Test's such as Grubbs' and Dixon's do take proper account of the distribution of the extreme order statistics from a normal distribution and should be used over Chauvenet " (Question 2) How would I get in touch with Joni using Stack Overflow? Thank you for your help.

Comment: @@Rethunk, I understand how extremely busy you are. Could you please just answer two little questions (Question 1) Do you agree with the following statement? : "Test's such as Grubbs' and Dixon's do take proper account of the distribution of the extreme order statistics from a normal distribution and should be used over Chauvenet " (Question 2) How would I get in touch with Joni using Stack Overflow? Thank you for your help.

Comment: @@Rethunk, I do not wish to join LinkedIn and Twitter to reach Joni. May I ask the best way to reach Joni Salonen using Stack Overflow? Thank you for your help.

Comment: I do not wish to join LinkedIn and Twitter to reach you. May I ask the best way to reach Joni Salonen using Stack Overflow? Thank you for your help.

Comment: Please post a comment to Joni's reply, and then perhaps Joni will follow up. Thanks. That's all I can do for now.

Comment: @@Rethunk, Thank you for your reply. 6 hours ago , I posted a Stack Overflow reply to Joni's reply. We would still like to get your inputs on Dixon's test.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. 6 hours ago , I posted a Stack Overflow reply to Joni's reply. We would still like to get your inputs on Dixon's test.

Comment: Given my recent work schedule, I don't foresee having the time to review this any further. That's all I can do for this post. Good luck!